# how to override core JS file in module

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, braintree, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to override

```
Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form
```

But i am not getting any progress. I have tried 
map

```
'Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form': 'module_name/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form-mixin'
```

mixins:

```
'Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form': {
'module_name/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form-mixin': true
```

Anyone know how to solve this any help or advice

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the Magento JS core and replace it by your custom Javascript.

Step 1:
Create a RequireJS configuration file requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "<default_component>": "<custom_component>"
    }
  }
};
```

- Where the following notation is used:

`<default_component>`: the name of the default component you replace

`<custom_component>`: the name of the custom component

Example, if you want to use custom navigation-menu.js script instead
   of the default menu widgets, your requirejs-config.js should contain
   the following:

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "menu": "/js/navigation-menu",
      "mage/backend/menu": "js/navigation-menu",
    }
  }
};
```

Step 2:
Place your requirejs-config.js file in one of the following directories (it depends on the location of your custom script):

- Your theme files:
- Your module view files: /view/frontend

The 2 steps I mention above is the shortest process for you to Override Magento JS Core in Magento 2. With this guide, you can manage the Magento JS Core in Magento 2 easily. Every store has a Magento JS Core in Magento 2 with many attributes.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: @ Muhammad Hasham. I have tried this
Steps i took =>
app/code/modukle_name/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

'Magento_Braintree/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form': 'Module_Name/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form'
but its not picking up
when i check frontend i get the following error "ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function()....."

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            '[core_module_name]/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form': {
                '[module_name]/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form': true
            },
        }
    }
```

map is to override the entire JS
mixins to extend